# Prove complete metric space for $I=]0,\infty[$ with $d(x,y)=\lvert\ln(x)-\ln(y)\rvert$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $I=]0,\infty[$ equipped with the metric $d(x,y)=\lvert\ln(x)-\ln(y)\rvert$, $\forall x,y \in I$. Prove that $(I,d)$ is complete.
Any help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What thoughts did you have about solving this?  Readers will be better able to reply if they have a sense of your background and where you got stuck in developing a proof.

Comment: There are a few older posts:
[Proving that the metric space $((0,\infty),d)$ is complete, with $d(x,y)=|\ln x-\ln y|$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175393/proving-that-the-metric-space-0-infty-d-is-complete-with-dx-y-ln-x) 
and [Proving that given metric space is complete: $X := (0,\infty)$ and $d:=|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371285/proving-that-given-metric-space-is-complete-x-0-infty-and-d-lnx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(x_n)$ is Cauchy sequence in $(I, d)$. Then, by definition of $d$, $(\ln(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R}, \left\vert \cdot \right\vert)$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with respect to the absolute value, $(\ln(x_n))$ has a limit $r \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(x_n) = r.$$

We also know that the exponential is continuous, which gives us
$$e^r = e^{\lim \ln(x_n)} = \lim e^{\ln(x_n)} = \lim x_n.$$

and additionally $e^r \in I$. Note that this is the limit of $x_n$ in $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$! However, we are lucky and this also holds in $(I,d)$ since
$$d(e^r, x_n) = |\ln(e^r) - \ln(x_n)| = |r - \ln(x_n)| \to 0$$

Hence, we have shown that if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(I,d)$, then it converges to an element of $I$ with respect to the metric $d$.